# Package/command to generate lang files in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a multilingual laravel 5.6 application and I have a ton of translation keys across my project defined both using @lang blade directive and trans() function.

I wish to find a way (command / package) that would allow me to scan the project for keys and generate files with the respective namespaces. I have found a package that would generate the files for keys like this:

```
trans('namespace.translation-string')
```

But I also need to support multiple level namespaces like this i.e. that it would automatically generate the nested namespace folders under each of the system's languages:

```
trans('namespace/another-namespace.translation-string')
```

Comment: https://github.com/themsaid/laravel-langman

Comment: I am trying this now, but I can't seem to make it generate the respective namespace folders or even files.

Comment: i think in-order for the package to work the namespace, it have to be `::` not `/` so it gets treated as a vendor https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#translations